# Tentando devolver múltiplos Futures dentro de um mesmo future

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Não tenho certeza se é possível fazer algo desse tipo, mas tenho a homePage do meu app onde serão carregadas algumas listas de dados, e elas vem individualmente de API's diferentes.
Minha home será montada num `FutureBuilder` e eu gostaria que ela terminasse de carregar quando todas as API's tivessem respondido já com os dados. Pra isso, eu estou tentando fazer uma função `async` que chama todas as funções que buscam na API e depois de conseguir todas elas, retorna um objeto contendo todos os dados que serão utilizados na homePage. Estou fazendo assim para montar o objeto:

```
getFullHome() async {
  List<Category> categories = await getCategory();
  List<Recipe> recipes = await getRecipes();
  final homeData = {categories, recipes};

  return homeData;
}
```

Essa função é chamada no atributo `future` do `FutureBuilder`, as duas funções que são chamadas ali dentro já estão retornando o tipo correto de List<>, mas dentro do objeto, está vindo apenas um atributo '_modifications':

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P.S.: É meu primeiro projeto em Flutter, ainda estou aprendendo a lidar com os Futures e as requisições em API, se existe uma maneira melhor de fazer isso eu ficaria feliz em saber =D

Comment: O seu problema é que você está retornando um _Set<List<Object>>_... Sempre coloque o tipo de retorno no seu método para facilitar o entendimento. Faça o seguinte, coloca um retorno do tipo `Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFullHome`. E o retorno mude para `final homeData = { "categorias": categories, "recipes": recipes}` dessa forma depois tu pode acessar através do _Map_ como `dados["categorias"]´

Comment: Não da para exemplificar melhor através de uma resposta, a questão de como controlar vários _Futures_ pois sua pergunta foi fechada. Mas o que lhe indiquei acima deve ajudar.